# Can't debug transactions that fail during the Web3.js estimateGas() call? No Tx Hash

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-debugging, ganache, gas-estimate

NOTE: I am doing my work with the Ganache v1.2.2 GUI client on a Linux Ubuntu 18.04 station.

There are many `revert` errors that happen during the `estimateGas()` call that precedes the actual Web3.js `send()` call.  Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, you don't get back a Tx hash for transactions that revert during  the `estimateGas()` call, so you can't debug the problem with the Truffle debugger.

Instead, the Web3.js *estimateGas()* throws a *promise rejection* during that method call.  I also checked carefully the Ganache log window and it never shows a Tx hash.  However it does show a Tx hash for all the Ethereum transactions that concluded successfully before the one that reverts, and it does show reverted transactions that revert during the actual `send()` call.

When this happens, I make a temporary change to my code to skip the `estimateGas()` call and go straight to the `send()` call with an artificially high gas price to make sure the transaction does not `revert` due to insufficient gas.  This is all done just so I can get back a `Tx Hash`and debug the transaction with the Truffle debugger.

This workflow works but it is tedious.  Is there a better way to debug a transaction that reverts during the `estimateGas()`  than this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a transaction hash because there is no transaction. If `estimateGas` reverts, then the actual transaction should revert as well. I don't know of a way to debug `estimateGas` calls, but you may want to set the properties for `estimateGas` the same as you will when you actually send the transaction (e.g. set the gas price and `from` address to what they will actually be.)